# Why does cucumber keep failling on jenkins, although tests pass?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cucumber

My cucumber test work well on command line, but when I run them in Jenkins/Hudson continuous integration, I get the following, but am not sure how to fix it:

```
11 scenarios (3 skipped, 3 pending, 5 passed)
78 steps (51 skipped, 3 pending, 24 passed)
0m3.238s
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Failed to send e-mail to kamilski81 because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured
Failed to send e-mail to i.wooten because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured
Failed to send e-mail to scott.j.rodgers because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured
Sending e-mails to: dev@sc.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

My final lines of my scripts:

```
cucumber
```

And i was advised to add 'exit 0' but then this breaks my Junit reports, so reporting is incorrect.

Comment: The message says your "Execute shell" step failed. Unless you provide more information, such as the contents of that step, we can't help you.

Comment: This is very interesting because I use Cucumber at work and we have the same problem; the tests run great locally but when ran by Jenkins on a slave with Firefox Driver, we experience sporadic failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think cucumber gives non-zero process exit code either because of skipped or because of pending tests. Try to get it to not run any skipped, then any pending, then any skipped or pending tests and see what exit codes it gives. To see the exit code (in Unix), run it with something like:

`cucumber ...args to select tests... ; echo $?`

Answer (score 4):

The cucumber --strict flag causes cucumber to return exit code 1 (e.g. fail) if there is pending scenarios. Jenkins (or any CI) will fail if there is a non-zero exit code.

I would check if you have a cucumber.yml file in your project as that is likely where your --strict is hiding.

Comment: Thanks. The hint to check the cucumber.yml was really helpful. FWIW, I removed `--strict` from my `cucumber.yml` and added a new profile `ci`, `ci: <%= std_opts %> features` that does not include the `--strict` (manually added to the other profiles where it made sense for me). This let me use `cucumber -p ci` on the CI service I'm using.