# Travis failing when Cucumber task pending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

As title says, my travis-ci instance is telling me that my build is failing when I have cucumber step definitions that are pending (not undefined) - is there a way to stop this behaviour?

I can understand the reason why, but the undefined behaviour I have is undefined by purpose - I have no intention on doing that feature RIGHT NOW, but I know I want to keep the step definition down so I don't forget what I came up with. The reason I ask is because this behaviour (with it failing when I have a pending task) could end up masking *real* failures that actually matter.

Comment: Can you post your `.travis.yml` file so we know what's being run? in addition, I think travis works on your exit codes so it's possible that cucumber provides a non-0 exit code when it has pending results. catching this in a bash script and returning 0 should fix your problem.

Comment: It's the default travis behaviour (i.e, no .travis.yml). And yeah, cucumber is exiting with 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982834/why-does-cucumber-keep-failling-on-jenkins-although-tests-pass) which should be useful for you, the answer that he gives is:

> I think cucumber gives non-zero process exit code either because of
>   skipped or because of pending tests. Try to get it to not run any
>   skipped, then any pending, then any skipped or pending tests and see
>   what exit codes it gives. To see the exit code (in Unix), run it with
>   something like:
>
> `cucumber ...args to select tests... ; echo $?`

So basically you want to figure out what args you can provide to cucumber to have it pass and then provide a `.travis.yml` that runs that command. an example rake task for cucumber jasmine and rspec is [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/):

```
task :travis do
  ["rspec spec", "rake jasmine:ci", "rake cucumber"].each do |cmd|
    puts "Starting to run #{cmd}..."
    system("export DISPLAY=:99.0 && bundle exec #{cmd}")
    raise "#{cmd} failed!" unless $?.exitstatus == 0
  end
end
```

And [read the docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/) for more info on creating a `.travis.yml`.

If all of that doesn't work, just create a bash script that catches the output and returns 0 in the right cases, I really doubt this is required though since I'm sure there's an option to cucumber to make it ignore pending.

EDIT: [the cucumber docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions) say:

> Pending steps
>
> When a Step Definition’s Proc invokes the #pending method, the step is
>   marked as yellow (as with undefined ones), reminding you that you have
>   work to do. If you use --strict this will cause Cucumber to exit with
>   1.

Which seems to imply that they will not exit with 0 if you don't call `--strict`

Comment: Managed to fix the issue by going into the cucumber script and removing references to `--strict`. I haven't made a travis file just yet because 1) i'm lazy and 2) see point 1) :P if it ain't broke, after all

Comment: Good call, if it ain't broke, its not my responsibility! Glad you sorted it out.